# Identifying Objects with Polygons

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I can't seem to find anything regarding how one identifies something like a torus with am oriented square. I would like to know the significance of: 
[image]

How does the rectangle depict the torus? Why are the orientations of $a$ and $b$ facing the same way? Why is the $b$ not going up on the right, and down on the left? Why does this rectangle uniquely depict a genus-1 manifold?

Comment: The lines indicate gluing spots and orientations. Take a piece of paper and put some Elmer's anywhere you see an arrow. Line it up with the other arrow of the same name and connect it so that the arrows point in the same direction. This analogy wont work so well for the second two  unless you have some kind of inter-dimensional paper

Comment: @DavidPeterson Ahh, so If I connect the $b$ edges, and pull the $a$ edges back together, I'll have a torus?

Comment: @DavidPeterson Should it be considered as a "rolling" out of the torus into a simple 2d space?

Comment: Yes, exactly right. More complicated objects will require some imagination. As far as 'rolling' out, I'm not sure I understand what you're seeing. More like cutting a torus straight through the tube and along the central circle. These cuts are the 'a' and 'b'

Comment: @DavidPeterson I don't quite understand the statement that the $4g$ edges become the union of $2g$ disks.

Comment: Try researching quotient maps and identification spaces.  Basically the lines are saying what points to identify with what points.

Comment: @Alan Do you have any suggested resources?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Munkres's Topology book is the one I'm using in my current general topology course, it's pretty good

Comment: @Alan In what chapter(s) are these things covered?

Comment: You may find these notes helpful: http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/ccooper/Topology/CHAP02%20Surfaces.pdf

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thank you, that makes complete sense. I'd never seen such a thing before opening Hatcher's book, so I was a bit confused.

Comment: These images are from Allen Hatcher's book, *Algebraic Topology* (page 5). Maybe read the rest of the book?

Comment: I commend your bravery for wandering into Hatcher's book without first reading a book like Munkres as @Alan suggests :-)